# Yet another Flex custom events in components question

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex4, custom-component

I can't seem to get one of the most basic uses of events working in Flex 4. I've followed multiple tutorials and looked everywhere. From what I can tell, I'm doing everything right, so there must be some stupid mistake somewhere.

I have a main application file that contains a button. On clicking the button, it fires a custom event which I want my listener in my child component to catch. The event IS firing. The child component event listener is NOT catching that event. No clue why. The custom event is copy-pasted from [Adobe's tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67fe7-7ffd.html) (minus the custom namespace and comments).

### Main Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       applicationComplete="init()" xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="enableChanged", type="EnableChangeEvent")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import EnableChangeEvent;
            import TestComponent;

            private function doDispatchEvent(event:MouseEvent):void {
                if(dispatchEvent(new EnableChangeEvent(EnableChangeEvent.ENABLE_CHANGED, true)))
                {
                    statusLabel.text = "Event was dispatched";
                }
            }

            public function init():void {
                myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doDispatchEvent);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button x="95" y="83" label="Button" id="myButton" />
    <s:Label x="230" y="83" text="" id="statusLabel" />
    <local:TestComponent x="95" y="150" width="300" height="400" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

### Child Component (Test)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width="100%" height="100%"
         initialize="init();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import EnableChangeEvent;

            private function doFinalAction(event:EnableChangeEvent):void {
                myLabel.text = "Custom Event Recieved";
            }

            private function init():void {
                addEventListener(EnableChangeEvent.ENABLE_CHANGED, doFinalAction);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label width="300" height="50" text="Should change on click" id="myLabel" />
</s:Group>
```

### Custom Event (from Adobe)

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class EnableChangeEvent extends Event
    {
        public function EnableChangeEvent(type:String, isEnabled:Boolean=false) {
            super(type);
            this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        }

        public static const ENABLE_CHANGED:String = "enableChanged";
        public var isEnabled:Boolean;

        override public function clone():Event {
            return new EnableChangeEvent(type, isEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timofei Davydik's answer it correct. Since the `Application` object dispatches the event, if you want your `TestComponent` object to catch it, you have to add a listener to a reference of the `Application` object from within your `TestComponent`. You can use the `TestComponent` object's inherited property "parentApplication" to get a reference to the `Application` object`.

Change the following code in TestComponent.mxml:

```
private function init():void 
{     
    this.parentApplication.addEventListener(EnableChangeEvent.ENABLE_CHANGED, doFinalAction);  

}// end function
```

**[UPDATE]**

Personally I feel like your going about using events the wrong way, so I made a similar flex application to demonstrate how to use events in flex.

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:components="components.*"
                       xmlns:events="events.*"
                       applicationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import events.EnableChangeEvent;

            public function init():void
            {     
                label1.text = "Application Complete!";

            }// end function

            private function onTestButtonEnableChanged(e:EnableChangeEvent):void
            {                     
                label2.text = "Enabled = " + e.isEnabled;   

            }// end function

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="50" />
    </s:layout>

    <components:TestButton id="testButton" label="CLICK!" enableChanged="onTestButtonEnableChanged(event)"  />
    <s:Label id="label1"/> 
    <s:Label id="label2"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

TestButton.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          click="onClick()">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="enableChanged", type="events.EnableChangeEvent")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[

            import events.EnableChangeEvent

            private var isEnabled:Boolean;

            private function onClick():void
            {
                isEnabled = !isEnabled;

                dispatchEvent(new EnableChangeEvent(EnableChangeEvent.ENABLE_CHANGED, isEnabled));

            }// end function

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

</s:Button>
```

The main difference between the applications is that the `Button` object, in this case the `TestButton` object, dispatches the `EnableChangeEvent` event when clicked. While dispatching the event we can parse the boolean value for the `_isEnabled` property of `TestButton` to the event. Before, the value is inverted using the line `isEnabled = !isEnabled`. Now we can make use of handling the event using the mxml declaration of the `TestButton` object with the xml attribute `enableChanged`.

Also instead of following tutorials you might want to try a book like the one i'm reading. It's called "Adobe Flash Builder 4 and Flex 4 Bible" by David Gassner which you can get as a paperback book or a book for your kindle.

Comment: If I understand your updated solution correctly, it is the opposite of what I need to do, namely, the child managing itself in response to changes in the parent (or in this case, the application itself). I am writing a small window management system, in which the application contains windows, each updating themselves in response to things such as the application window being resized. The solution you give has global application responsible for resizing all windows.

Comment: On further consideration, you're probably right about having a pure hierarchy where the child knows nothing about the parent at all. However, for now, it is more compact and effective to have the child know one thing about the parent so I don't have to write a separate child manager object to sit between the application and the children. This contrived example doesn't illustrate why I need to arrange my program this way. Either way, applying the event listener to the parent worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Taurayi is correct, but to get you current code working with just one change, edit the init of Test Component to look like the following:

```
private function init():void 
{ 
     FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(EnableChangeEvent.ENABLE_CHANGED, doFinalAction);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean using `parentApplication` was incorrect or that using `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` is the better alternative. I'm still learning Flex so if you could explain it would help me out.

Comment: FlexGlobals refers to the top level application. Using parentApplication may give a ref to an embedded swf if your using any. As far as i know FlexGlobals is the Flex 4 best practice method

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me, I was wondering what the difference was, since they both seemed like the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your application object dispatches the custom event. Why do you expect your group to "catch" this event? It won't. Custom events have neither capturing nor bubbling phase. So, only listeners added to your application object will listen to this event.

Comment: FYI - Custom events that are dispatched by objects on the display list can be bubbled.

Comment: Custom events can bubble up to Application level same as any other event, just have to set up you event correctly: http://blogagic.com/133/adding-events-to-flex-custom-components#customclass

Comment: I was wrong, sorry. The "bubbles" parameter is false by default in Event constructor.

Comment: There's also the fact that as a new person to event-based programming, I assumed events applied globally to all objects with compatible listeners, regardless of their location in the application (a table of listeners and a table of events possible that would be checked each frame, for example).